# PHP: "max execution time" immediately

Tags: php, execution-time

I am currently running a large website based on our own framework. When uploading a picture we occasionaly get a  `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded` within a fraction of a second. So I dont think the execution time is actually exceeded.

Does anyone have a clue what might cause this?

PHP version: 5.3.3

Comment: recurring loops tend to do this.

Comment: A temporary space-time fluctuation around your server that causes time to move faster within it?

Answer (score 1):

increase  the execution time in  php.ini file .in php.ini file search for "max_execution_time = 600".Default value is 600.

If you are using linux/ubuntu your php.ini file will be in lampp/etc/php.ini